# How to keep one row inside a list active (once)? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am encountering is that I want the user only to be able to click on a spesific row, without having the oppertuinity to activate multiple rows.

If the user clicks on row1 then I want this row to be active. If he then clicks on row2, then the active state changes from row1 to row2.

```
    $(function () {

        $('body').on('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });

        $('[name="SearchDualList"]').keyup(function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (code == '9') return;
            if (code == '27') $(this).val(null);
            var $rows = $(this).closest('.dual-list').find('.list-group li');
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            $rows.show().filter(function () {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example with table:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
  $('tr').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
tr.active { background-color: #f1f1f1 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>one</td></tr>
    <tr><td>two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>four</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle class from previously selected row:

```
$('body').on('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function () {
    $('.active').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: this will clear anything `.active`, which might be other unrelated objects in other contexts

Answer (score 0):

You can add something clearing all other lines

```
$('.list-group .list-group-item').removeClass('active');
```

More efficient code might be available if you reveal your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()` function in the click handler to iterate on items and find the last clicked one, so you remove the `active` class from it before toggeling this class to the new one being clicked

```
$('body').on('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function (event) {
    var parent = $(this).parents('.list-group'),
        children = parent.find('.list-group-item');
    children.each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opz447b6/)